# Writing to file while reading from another file

Tags: c++, file-io, stream

Can we do both in a function, while using the elements of input file, can we write the results in output file same time?

inside of *while* statement is true?

```
void solve(string inputFileName, string outputFileName)
{
//declaring variables
string filename = inputFileName;

//Open a stream for the input file
ifstream inputFile;
inputFile.open( filename.c_str(), ios_base::in );

//open a stream for output file
outputfile = outputFileName;
ofstream outputFile;
outputFile.open(outputfile.c_str(), ios_base::out);

while(!inputFile.eof())
{
    inputFile >> number;    //Read an integer from the file stream
    outputFile << number*100 << "\n"
    // do something

}

//close the input file stream
inputFile.close();

//close output file stream
outputFile.close();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this? I think it should work.

Comment: You might want to read about RAII (resource acquisition is initialization). Your `close` statements are either superfluous (if the file is closed anyway) or not exception-safe (if the file is not closed anyway; then the `close` statement will not be executed in case of an exception, which probably causes problems). I guess your code is ok due to closing of the file on destruction of the stream object, but you should understand why the close statements can be deleted.

Comment: Don't use `eof()`. It's never correct. Every day about 200 people get this wrong on StackOverflow...

Comment: @KerrekSB But why? Posters very rarely explain. But once someone told me his professor had told him to do it.

Answer (score 2):

```
while(!inputFile.eof())
```

doesn't work very well, because it tests if the *previous* operation failed, not if the next one will be successful.

Instead try

```
while(inputFile >> number)
{
    outputFile << number*100 << "\n"
    // do something

}
```

where you test each input operation for success and terminate the loop when the read fails.

Answer (score 1):

You can, the input and output stream are independent from each other, so mixing them together in statements has no combined effect.